# how to join table that still retain all values from the main table

Tags: sql, sql-server, view

i got 3 tables but for now i'm only using 2 for testing

AccntTbl

```
         id     accnt      amount       date
        ---------------------------------------
         1       xxx        10.00      1/1/2016
         2       yyy        20.00      1/1/2016
         3       zzz        30.00      1/1/2016
```

IssuedTbl

```
         id     accnt      issued       dateIssue
        ------------------------------------------
         1       xxx        5.00        1/10/2016
         1       xxx        5.00        2/14/2016
         2       yyy       10.00        2/15/2016
```

and i want the result would look something like this..if in JANUARY

```
        id     accnt       amount    issued    balance  
      -------------------------------------------------
         1      xxx         10.00     5.00      5.00
         2      yyy         20.00     0.00     20.00
         3      zzz         30.00     0.00     30.00
```

and if it's in FEBRUARY

```
       id     accnt        amount    issued    balance
      -------------------------------------------------
        1       xxx         10.00     10.00     0.00
        2       yyy         20.00     10.00    10.00
        3       zzz         30.00      0.00    30.00
```

and here's the query that i come up with

```
       SELECT   AccntTbl.id, AccntTbl.accnt, AccntTbl.amount, 
                SUM(IssuedTbl.issued) as issued 
       FROM     AccntTbl LEFT JOIN IssuedTbl 
       ON       AccntTbl.id = IssuedTbl.id
       WHERE    (MONTH(IssuedTbl.dateIssue BETWEEN 1 AND 2)) AND
                (YEAR(AccntTbl.date)= 2016)
       GROUP BY AccntTbl.id, AccntTbl.accnt, AccntTbl.amount
```

but the result is not what i'v been expecting only id from `1 & 2` would show from the result..i want to show all the values from the AccntTbl with their values from the IssuedTbl..glad from any help..tnx :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are using `LEFT OUTER JOIN` and you want to filter some records from *Right* table then you need to move the right table **filter** to `ON` condition else `LEFT OUTER JOIN` will be implicitly converted to `INNER JOIN`

To make it short, `WHERE` clause you **reject** rows with `NULL` which are produced by `LEFT OUTER JOIN` for *non matching records*

```
SELECT A.id, 
       A.accnt, 
       A.amount, 
       Sum(I.issued) AS issued 
FROM   accnttbl A
       LEFT JOIN issuedtbl I
              ON A.id = I.id 
                 AND Month(I.dateissue) BETWEEN 1 AND 2 -- Right table filter
WHERE  Year(A.date) = 2016 
GROUP  BY A.id, 
          A.accnt, 
          A.amount
```

Comment: i'll try that out mate..tnx :)

Comment: i add another table in that query...with the same filter..and the result is not wat i'm expecting..why is that ?